# How to animate width depending on a changing variable

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm currently trying to develop a progress bar which grows or shrinks depending on the number of inputs that aren't empty.

I've tried 2 solutions to animate the bar depending on the var *percentage*.

**First one:**

I've tried to write the transition style inline like this in App.js:

```
  <div className="progress-div" >
      <div style={{transition:"all 500ms",  width: `${progress}%`}} className="progress"/>
  </div>
```

and in the App.css:

```
 .progress-div {
    background-color:#E2E2F6;
    border-radius: .5rem;
  }
  
  .progress {
    background-color: #8B8CC7;
    height: 15px;
  }
```

**Second one:**

```
  <div className="progress-div" >
      <div style={{width: `${progress}%`}} className="progress"/>
  </div>
```

---

```
.progress-div {
    background-color:#E2E2F6;
    border-radius: .5rem;
  }
  
  .progress {
    background-color: #8B8CC7;
    height: 15px;
    transition: all 500ms
  }
```

Neither of those worked, I guess it won't because I'm giving the width in the inline code, but I don't know how I could pass the variable to the css file or have another way around to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried both of your solutions, both work on my sandbox [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-tdd-7nwui?file=/src/App.js)

The only thing that comes to my mind is incorrect "progress" variable value, please check that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes it was working. I found the problem, I was creating the progress bar on a custom component, and when calling it in the main function the transition wouldn't work. But instead of using a custom component and using it directly solved my problem!